# Jquery FullCalendar enhancement questions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, modal-dialog

I would like to know if some hacks are already present or some ways to do the same.

1.Instead of consecutive days click events in FullCalendar plugin,how can I make the user to select the days user wants from a month view say Days,2,5,7 and then plan an event based on these days.
   Event is control + click on days.

- The way I approached is  Onclick of day,color the cell if control is pressed and then continue the coloring until the key is released.And once released,recognise the days based on color of cell/style applied.  But that I assume is adding complexity ,and I think I am going in wrong direction.

  1. How to make the headers of calendar draggable ? Say as in MS Excel column expand and shrink.
  2. I want to display the same page in another modal window using Jquery Modal ,but its adding the contents to same page,causing my calendar to be shown twice.
       -I tried dynamically including contents to the div on Modal ,but its again created on same page.

Help required.